# SqlAlchemy setter, getter

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, documentation, getter-setter

I was interested in one question.  Usually, in order to get / put data from the database and decode / encode the logic is written in routers or in separate functions that are called anyway in routers.  Is it possible to call these very functions in the model in decorators?  I would be grateful if you share a link to the documentation where there is a similar situation.

I used @property, @hybrid_property ... like

```
...
@property
def test_get(self) -> List[Dict[str, str]]:
  if self.test:
    return [{'test', 'test'}] # or function callback
  return []
```

I will write in more detail. I've run into a buffer full issue when using a JSON field to store a large amount of data in a database using PostageSQL and FastAPI. I store geographic coordinates (like latitude and longitude) in a List of Dict {lat: 55.555, lon: 55.555}
To reduce the size of the data, I decided to compress the data and also encode in Base64. The problem is that my schemas will not behave correctly because of this. Therefore, I wanted to use SQLAlchemy getter so that when selecting data from the database, it would immediately receive coordinates in the form of a List of Dict. However, I did not meet documentation with an approximate application.

```
db = SessionLocal()
point = db.query(MapPoint).filter(MapPoint.id == point_id).first()
print(point.coordinates) # [{lat: 55.555, lon: 55.555}]
```

Comment: Yeah, sry. I need to ask a more specific question with clear examples.

Comment: Have you seen https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/custom_types.html which allows you to create a custom type that serializes/deserializes to/from another field type? That way you can encode when a value gets updated and deserialize it automagically when it gets fetched again? (I don't think base64 encoding the content makes any sense, but I might be missing something obvious in your example).

Comment: you're right, it makes no sense, I just decided to use base64 for visual compactness.  And yes, I wanted to use a getter, because as I understand it, they allow you to set your own behavior for certain data.  Therefore, if you install a getter that, when requested to the database, immediately returns the unzipped data, I would get rid of the repetitive code. Thanks again for your help and answer.